# Basis for vector space with complex vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

> Find a basis for $V = \operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$, where  $v_1=(-i,-i,i), v_2=(5,1,0), v_3=(4,0,1)$.

This is asking to find a basis for the column space of $$\begin{pmatrix}-i&5&4\\ -i&1&0\\ i&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

I have that $$\begin{pmatrix}-i&5&4\\ -i&1&0\\ i&0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix} \implies x_1=ix_3,x_2=-x_3.$$ So any vectors that would form a basis for $V$ would be of the form $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(ix_3,-x_3,x_3)?$ I'm a bit confused how can I construct the basis from here?

Comment: this would be rather a basis of the Kernel, not of the column space.

Answer (score 1):

You solved for the *kernel* (=nullspace) of the given matrix, and found that it's the span of $(i,-1,1)$, which has dimension $1$.

By the rank-nullity theorem we know that the rank of the matrix must be $2$, which means that any two independent vectors in the column space form a basis of the column space.

So, just take any $2$ columns of the matrix, it's easy to see that they are not parallel, hence are linearly independent.
Specifically, $v_1,v_2$ is such a basis.

You can also note that $iv_1=(1,1,-1)$ and so $v_3=v_2-i\,v_1$.

Comment: I see thanks. I've tried to find lectures on how to find the basis for column space, but there isn't many. It seems that they always perform row reducing and then just like magic the columns that contain pivots determine the basis vectors.